# regex to get all occurrences with optional next character or end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, wildcard

I have a string separated by forward slashes, and wildcards are denoted by beginning with a `$`:

```
/a/string/with/$some/$wildcards
```

I need a regex to get all wildcards (without the "$"), where wildcards can either have more "string" ahead of them (and the next character should always be a forward slash) or will be at the end of the string. Here is where I'm at (it matches to the end of the string rather to the next "/"):

```
//Just want to match $one
var string = "/a/string/with/$one/wildcard"
var re = /\$(.*)($|[/]?)/g
var m = re.exec(string)

console.log(m);
// [ '$one/wildcard',
//   'one/wildcard',
//   '',
//   index: 123,
//   input: '/a/string/with/$one/wildcard'
// ]
```

Here was a previous attempt (that doesn't account for wildcards that are at the end of the string):

```
//Want to match $two and $wildcards
var string = "/a/string/with/$two/$wildcards"
var re = /\$(.*)\//g
var m = re.exec(string)

console.log(m);
// [ '$two/',
//   'two',
//   '',
//   index: 123,
//   input: '/a/string/with/$two/$wildcards'
// ]
```

I've searched around for matching a character *or* end of string and have found several answers, but none that try to account for multiple matches. I *think* I need the ability to match the next character as a `/` *greedily*, and *then* try to match the end of the string.

The desired functionality is to take the input string:

```
/a/string/with/$two/$wildcards
```

and transform it to the following:

```
/a/string/with/[two]/[wildcards]
```

Thanks in advance! Also, apologies if this has been explicitly covered in detail, I was unable to find a replica after various searches.

Comment: data sample + result expected please ;)

Comment: @Blag, did you read the question? I think all of this is explicitly defined.

Comment: This might be what you're after: https://regex101.com/r/cV9aN9/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
/\$([^\/]+)/g
```

And the you can use the `replace()` function:

```
"/a/string/with/$two/$wildcards".replace(/\$([^\/]+)/g, "[$1]");
// "/a/string/with/[two]/[wildcards]"
```

Comment: I think it is missing the `/g` at the end of the regex, but I believe this works! Thanks!

Comment: @MandM the G is missing in the 1st, but it's in the replace ;)

Comment: Actually, it looks like you have it in the `replace`, but it would be more correct to add it in the first regex. Will accept when it lets me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` function on the string like so:

```
var s = '/a/string/with/$two/$wildcards';
s.replace(/\$([a-zA-Z]+)/g, '[$1]')';
```

`s` will have the value:

```
/a/string/with/[two]/[wildcards]
```

Here's a reference to replace documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: black list is better than white list in this case ;) so `[^\/]`

Comment: MMSs, thanks for the answer, but I think caeth slipped in ahead of you. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Blag sure, I agree, no need to edit my answer I guess now, caeth already answer that way